# Ubuntu Apache FTP Not Updating Files, Some Kind of Cache?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ftp

I'm on a DigitalOcean droplet, Ubuntu Apache Server with a [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) installation.

I'm having a really weird issue where files uploaded to the server through FTP are clearly on the server, but the updates aren't reflected when served on my website. It was bad enough that I could get the index page of a directory showing image files in the directory, but when I clicked the image file link I would get a not found error.

Why is this happening? I have updated my CSS through the FTP and that won't work now either, the images started showing after a while but the CSS is not being served through the cache, it is fetching it from the server and it still appears as the old version.

My local computer was having networking issues, could this be interfering somehow? Please provide suggestions or requests for more information.

Oh, by the way, checking the network tab I get **a 304 not modified** instead of a regular 200? Is this the issue? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use FTP a kitten dies.

Please stop doing this - use sftp.

There is something called ftps which is almost as silly as ftp - that makes kittens cry.

"checking the network tab" tells you what's happening at your browser - not at your server. There's a lot of hardware in between. Ssh into your server and use either 'curl -i $YOURURL' or 'wget --server-response $YOURURL' to find out what is coming out of your webserver.

These commands will not give a 304 response (without a lot of other configuration) but will show the content and caching information you are currently serving your files with (which you told us nothing about). If you still see the old content then check you are uploading the file to the right location.

If you are seeing the new content, then something else is caching the content between your server and your browser. Learn how http caching works and switch to a more appropriate policy.